# Office 2007 updates after installing Visual Studio & SQL Server 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, office-2007, windows-update

I just installed Visual Studio 2008 TS and SQL Server 2005 Enterprise and I get a bunch on Office 2007 updates in Windows Update. I don't even have office installed.

Should I:

1. Just install the updates (~20MB only)
2. Don't install and hide them (possible security issue)
3. Uninstall  to get rid of those updates

I already uninstalled some components that could cause these updates to show up. I will check updates again after restart.

I am running Windows 7 x64 and even though SQL Server 2005 is not supported, I read it runs fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the [Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2007/08/20/what-is-microsoft-visual-studio-web-authoring-component.aspx) was the culprit.

I decided to just install the updates.